# error al crear registro ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RatingsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Al intentar insertar un registro me sale un error en el controlador

> Valoracion(#47310743451000) expected, got String(#47310719254620)

Esta es la instrucción:

```
sql=  Rating.create(:user_id => params[:rating][:user_id],
                    :app_id=> params[:rating][:app_id],
                    :valoracion_id => app.id,
                    :valoracion => params[:rating][:valoracion][nombre])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está aquí

```
:valoracion => params[:rating][:valoracion][nombre]
```

Cuando haces un create y pasas una key con el nombre de la relación :valoracion, se espera que le pases un objeto Valoracion y no un string.

Debería ser de esta manera o similar:

```
Rating.create(:user_id => params[:rating][:user_id],
                    :app_id=> params[:rating][:app_id],
                    :valoracion_id => app.id,
                    :valoracion => Valoracion.find_by_nombre(params[:rating][:valoracion][nombre]))
```

De igual forma me confunde que asignes al mismo tiempo :valoracion y :valoracion_id en el mismo create. Me gustaría ver la clase Rating para ver sus asociaciones.

Comment: `class Rating < ApplicationRecord                                                                                                         
        belongs_to :app
       belongs_to :user
end`                                  esta es la clase rating

Comment: el campo valoración es la valoración valga la redundancia que le da un usuario a una app sobre algun criterio

Comment: Tienes una clase Valoracion?